# React Data Table Expandable Rows : how to pass additional Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-data-table-component

Reading the [Docs](https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/expandable-basic--basic) for `React Data Table`, there seems to be a way to pass additional Props to an `expandableRowsComponent`.

This is copy-pasted from the docs:

### expandableComponentProps

expandableComponentProps allows you to pass additional props to your expander component and prevents TypeScript from complaining:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DataTable, { ExpanderComponentProps } from 'react-data-table-component';

interface Row {
    title: string;
    director: string;
    year: string;
}

interface Props extends ExpanderComponentProps<Row> {
    // currently, props that extend ExpanderComponentProps must be set to optional.
    someTitleProp?: string;
}

const ExpandableRowComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ data, someTitleProp }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <p>{someTitleProp}</p>
            <p>{data.title}</p>
            <p>{data.director}</p>
            <p>{data.year}</p>
        </>
    );
};
```

I understand the above clearly.

However, this `ExpandableRowComponent` is passed as a *parameter* to the `DataTable` Component. It is not called as a React component itself, so I do not clearly see how to pass the additional prop `someTitleProp`.

```
function MyComponent({ someTitleProp }) {
    return 
     <DataTable
      columns={columns} 
      data={data} 
      expandableRows 
      expandableRowsComponent={ExpandedComponent} //where does someTitleProp go?
    />;
}
```

I've tried a few things, but so far all I get are either errors, or someTitleProp is undefined in the ExpandedComponent.

How do I pass `someTitleProp` to the ExpandedComponent?

Comment: you probably need to make a HOC (Higher Order Component) for the ExpandableRowComponent.

Comment: @Jackstine I did make a higher order component, following the instructions in the Docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to pass additional props to the `expandableRowsComponent` parameter is to pass them as a named object to `expandableRowsComponentProps` parameter.

```
function MyComponent({ someTitleProp }) {
    return 
     <DataTable
      columns={columns} 
      data={data} 
      expandableRows 
      expandableRowsComponent={ExpandedComponent}
      expandableRowsComponentProps={{"someTitleProp": someTitleProp}}    
    />;
}
```

Comment: I take my answer back, this is the best way to do it!

Comment: this works and in that way you can pass functions as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can this be used to close all the other expanded rows?  Trying to find a solution which does that (one row expanded only and if clicking new rows, closes prior row)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is going at it this way :

- First you make your `ExpandableRowComponent` a Higher order function

```
const ExpandableRowComponent: (someTitleProp: string) => React.FC<Props> = (someTitleProp) => ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <p>{someTitleProp}</p>
            <p>{data.title}</p>
            <p>{data.director}</p>
            <p>{data.year}</p>
        </>
    );
};
```

- Second you call the function with the desired parameter in the DataTable props like so:

```
function MyComponent({ someTitleProp }) {
    return 
     <DataTable
      columns={columns} 
      data={data} 
      expandableRows 
      expandableRowsComponent={ExpandedComponent(someTitleProps)} //where does someTitleProp go?
    />;
}
```

And that should solve your issue.

Comment: I tried this, but got errors. It did not work.

Comment: Here's a sandbox with the solution : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-data-table-sandbox-custom-grow-wrap-forked-0vovz?file=/src/index.js